# Inform Employer About Job Interview Abroad

Tags: interviewing, united-states, new-job, travel, international

I'm currently looking for jobs and one of the jobs for which I've had a preliminary interview will require me to fly to their country (Netherlands) for a final in person interview.

My current company does contract work for the US Department of Defense, and therefore I am required to inform them of all travel abroad.

Since any such travel will almost certainly be very late notice (at least by international travel standards), is there any particular way I should go about informing them of my last minute travel?

My current best idea is to just say that "I found a great last minute deal to the Netherlands" and leave it at that.  Ideas?

Comment: Lying in a job which presumably requires clearance seems like a very bad idea...

Comment: It is also remarkably foolish of you to ask this question with what is presumably your real name linked to your GitHub account. You are essentially planning to lie to the government in a case where they care about security.

Comment: "Next week, I'm flying to the Netherlands for personal reasons." Who do you have to tell anyway? HR?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser the way I read it, OP never intends to lie, they are trying to keep it vague while communicating the information and they're looking for choice of words.

Comment: "`Lying in a job which presumably requires clearance seems like a very bad idea.`" , whereas the OP would be lying to ***get out of a job*** which presumably requires clearance

Comment: "Hi boss. During time off I'm going to The Netherlands. See you when I get back. Greetz."

Comment: Please clarify: Does your employer gets to deny you the right to travel? Do you need to provide proof of some kind? Do you need days off which you don't have to spare?

Comment: Not sure how it goes where you work but I you tell my boss I was going to a marriage, hence why the short-term notice of the travel. I'd ask to get vacation days to take this trip (don't think any excuse would dismiss you from work without presenting proof). And by telling I mean say personally, just a verbal notice. No paper trail left anywhere. HR needs your boss to approve of vacation days, not of your reason. A good boss would also accept "personal reasons" as an excuse, but I would avoid this option, as he might suspect worse than the truth (i.e. that you are about to die or something).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Inform Employer About Job Interview

It is usually very bad idea to inform your current employer about ANY job interviews.

I was in a very similar situation, just that the government had nothing to do with my job. I told my employer that I am going to visit that country. After I returned, I took my time to think about the job offer. When I had the final decision, I informed my employer that I will leave the company.

Now, **read your contract and other paperwork carefully**. If you have to inform them about going abroad, inform them. If you do not have to inform them about attending interviews, then don't.

If they ask about reasons for visiting the said country, claim tourism. You might even allow yourself a very short vacation (1-3 days) for some sight-seeing, and then you will not even be lying. I actually did exactly that, and I actually had a vacation of about 6 days, additional to having the interview.

Comment: I would definitely recommend putting in a little sightseeing time. It gives you something to talk about when colleagues ask you about your trip. Also, getting a good look at the place may help making your decision about the job. (And as someone from the Netherlands, I recommend trying to get beyond the tourist areas to see what the country is really like.)

Comment: @ObscureOwl: I agree, seeing things other than the main touristic areas is very welcome. I did it in the past (just tourist, not job related, not Netherlands), and I regret nothing - except insufficient time to explore more.

Comment: @ObscureOwl Whilst I agree with visiting non-tourist areas, some people may need to consider whether it would be safe for them to do so, though this won't be an issue for the OP. It is only if there are any political issues (at which point you would reconsider working there), but also if your ethnicity/religion might not be as tolerated outside of the big cities.

Comment: @Monstar that might be an issue in some countries, but the Netherlands are pretty safe throughout.

Comment: @ObscureOwl I agree, it was more of a general statement in case anyone else saw this. But then, I'm sure those people affected would have an idea.

Comment: Of course, basic personal safety rules should be followed by everyone in any country - avoid dark places, avoid places with not many people, avoid friendships with strangers (or at least do it with caution)... We do not discuss here about careless people :)

Answer (score 10):

Copying your words: (*emphasis mine*)

> *.... therefore I am required to **inform** them of all travel abroad.*

So do that, *inform* them. As you mentioned, you don't need an *approval*, so just keep them informed about the travel. You can mention personal reasons as the purpose of the travel.

Whatever happens, don't lie.

Comment: "I'm taking a personal trip to the Netherlands on X date to Y date" is both factual and doesn't drop you in it.

Comment: @JayGould That's exactly what I'm advising.